# Dask ignores knowledge about divisions for parquet dataset

Tags: dask, parquet, pyarrow, dask-dataframe, fastparquet

I've got a parquet dataset located in the directory `"dataset_path"` with an index column `date`.

The metadata was created by dask and the relevant schema data looks as follows:

```
date: timestamp[us]
-- schema metadata --
pandas: '{"index_columns": ["date"], ...
```

I read the dataset into a dask dataframe using pyarrow:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.read_parquet("dataset_path", engine="pyarrow", calculate_divisions=True)
```

Just to be sure that the divisions are known to dask, I run:

```py
print(ddf.divisions)
```

```
(Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'), ...
```

Nevertheless, dask seems to ignore the divisions in many operations. For example, running the following code

```py
ddf.loc[ddf.index == pd.Timestamp("2020-01-01")].compute()
```

after enabling debugging with

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format="%(message)s", level=logging.DEBUG)
```

outputs to the log:

```
open file: ./dataset_path/part.0.parquet
open file: ./dataset_path/part.1.parquet
open file: ./dataset_path/part.2.parquet
...
```

So dask processes all files in the dataset. Even though from the divisions it's clear that only the first file can match.

What am I missing here? Any help how I can tell dask to look only at the relevant files is greatly appreciated.

The same problem arises with other index-based operations. For instance merging on the index with

```py
pdf = pd.DataFrame({"y": 0}, index=pd.Index([pd.Timestamp("2020-01-01")]))
dd.merge(ddf, pdf, left_index=True, right_index=True).compute()
```

also opens all files in the dataset.

I also tried switching from pyarrow to fastparquet as an engine. But the problem persists.

Finally, here's some code to produce a dummy version of `"my_dataset"` to get a minimal working example:

```py
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import pandas as pd

def write_parquet_timeseries(path: str, start: date, end: date):
    for part, pdf in enumerate(generate_timeseries(start, end)):
        dd.to_parquet(
            dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions=1),
            path,
            engine="pyarrow",
            overwrite=part == 0,
            append=part > 0,
            write_metadata_file=True,
        )

def generate_timeseries(start: date, end: date):
    start0, end0 = None, start
    while end0 < end:
        start0, end0 = end0, end0 + relativedelta(months=1)
        yield timeseries(start0, end0)

def timeseries(start: date, end: date, num_rows: int = 2**16, num_cols: int = 2**4):
    index = pd.Index(pd.date_range(start, end, inclusive="left"), name="date").repeat(num_rows)
    return pd.DataFrame({f"x{i}": range(i, len(index) + i) for i in range(num_cols)}, index=index)

write_parquet_timeseries("dataset_path", date(2020, 1, 1), date(2021, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dask is only able to "push down" a limited subset of selection operations to the loader layer. For example, if you replace

```
ddf.loc[ddf.index == pd.Timestamp("2020-01-01")].compute()
```

with the syntactically simpler

```
ddf.loc[pd.Timestamp("2020-01-01")].compute()
```

you should get the load optimization you are after. This is because in the first case, dask doesn't know that you want to use `ddf.index` for the purposes of selection only, and so it considers all of the values in the dataframe. Future higher-level optimizations might be able to spot and use such patterns.

Comment: Great, thank you! This does the trick. Is there a similar way to speed up the merge operation that I mentioned in my question? Actually, these slower than expected index-based merges are what motivated my question.

Comment: Following your suggestion, for the simple merge of my question I can first apply the restriction `ddf.loc[pdf.index]` to get the optimization. I guess restricting the index range in a similar way might also speed up more sophisticated merges. I'll try.

Comment: If you are merging on the index, this should work. You may need to make the second dataframe a dask dataframe with known divisions too.

Comment: This is what I would have expected, too. Hence, my post. But as far as I can see, this is not what dask does. Just try to replace the argument `pdf` given to `dd.merge` above by `dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions=1)` (that's a dask dataframe with known divisions). This will still unnecessarily open every file in the dataset.